# How to autofill webpage with specific and pre-made data?

Tags: html, webpage, auto-form-fill, autosave, form-fill

Ok, lets get straight to the thing... The main purpose of my asking is to make things effortless as that is  gonna be so useful for me. But I just dont know how to do it, even though I think it might be possible to do it unofficially if there's no official way.

I'm a private seller in a website and the thing is that recently, a ton of listings (items I'm selling) was deleted from my store by error. The shame is that the website can't restore them which is so annoying for me as I would have to put back all descriptions, titles and pictures in the right order for each items to put back online... Just imagine how long it is to bring back all of them manually.

Following this, I tried to test if this could be done by myself alone (I'm using Google Chrome). So in the website, what I tried doing is going in "sell my item" button to have access in the typical web page that all selling website have (when you have to put title, description, pictures...etc of your item) before pressing the confirmation button to put the listing online.

One time I filled that page, I saved the page into three type of html page from what Google Chrome is offering in term of possibilities (the thing to make you read the web page offline). There's three kind of html saving including two that dont work well (only save text of the page) but the last one (the heaviest that also create a folder) is actually working flawlessly, with everything of what I've put in the page (title, description, pictures...etc).

For me, the main goal of having this html page is to import all the content of it concerning the title of the item, the categories, description and pictures of the listing online and blank of the same "sell my item" webpage. That being said, that's to make things without having to fill all the missing part but instead, all automatically and for all my listing that I'm willing to save in case listings will again get deleted in further time. Like something that would autofill the webpage but not only with words but also pictures, categories to select...etc

I tried severals possibilities but it seems that concerning my knowledge, this isn't possible... If someone's enough knowledge about this specific case, I would like to first know if this is possible, then know how this could be done, please.